# Simple Android Calculator

Tags: android, calculator

I am trying to build a simple calculator. Following is the activity file:

```
 package com.example.calcsimple;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnClr , btn0 , btn1 , btn2 , btn3 , btn4, btn5 , btn6 , btn7 , btn8 , btn9 , btnAdd , btnSub , btnMul , btnDiv , btnEq;
TextView textView1 ; 
double i1 , i2 , result=0;
boolean newValue = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    btnClr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClr);
    btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
    btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnSub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
    btnMul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMul);
    btnDiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);
    btnEq = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEq);

    btn0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            textView1.append("0");
        }
    });

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if(newValue == true)
                 textView1.setText("1");
             else
                 textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() +  "1");

             newValue = false;
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if(newValue == true)
                 textView1.setText("2");
             else
                 textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() +  "2");

             newValue = false;
        }
    });

    btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if(newValue == true)
                 textView1.setText("3");
             else
                 textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() +  "3");

             newValue = false;
        }
    });

    btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if(newValue == true)
                 textView1.setText("4");
             else
                 textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() +  "4");

             newValue = false;
        }
    });

    btn5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if(newValue == true)
                 textView1.setText("5");
             else
                 textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() +  "5");

             newValue = false;
        }
    });

    btn6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if(newValue == true)
                 textView1.setText("6");
             else
                 textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() +  "6");

             newValue = false;
        }
    });

    btn7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if(newValue == true)
                 textView1.setText("7");
             else
                 textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() +  "7");

             newValue = false;
        }
    });

    btn8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if(newValue == true)
                 textView1.setText("8");
             else
                 textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() +  "8");

             newValue = false;
        }
    });

    btn9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if(newValue == true)
                 textView1.setText("9");
             else
                 textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString() +  "9");

             newValue = false;
        }
    });


    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i1 = Double.parseDouble(textView1.getText().toString());
            textView1.setText("");
            result = result + i1;
            textView1.setText(Double.toString(result));
            newValue=true ;  


        }
    });

    btnSub.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i1 = Double.parseDouble(textView1.getText().toString());
            result = result - i1;
            textView1.setText(Double.toString(result));
            newValue=true ;  
            textView1.setText("");
        }
    });

    btnMul.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i1 = Double.parseDouble(textView1.getText().toString());
            result = result * i1;
            textView1.setText(Double.toString(result));
            newValue=true ;  
            textView1.setText("");
        }
    });

    btnDiv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i1 = Double.parseDouble(textView1.getText().toString());
            result = result / i1;
            textView1.setText(Double.toString(result));
            newValue=true ;  
            textView1.setText("");

        }
    });

    btnEq.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            textView1.setText(Double.toString(result));
        }
    });

    btnClr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            textView1.setText("");
            newValue=true;
            result = 0 ;
            i1=0;
        }
    });

    }


}
```

Following is the XML layout file:

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="6dp"
    android:layout_y="109dp"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="88dp"
    android:layout_y="108dp"
    android:text="2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="174dp"
    android:layout_y="106dp"
    android:text="3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn4"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="6dp"
    android:layout_y="184dp"
    android:text="4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="4dp"
    android:text="" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn5"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="92dp"
    android:layout_y="186dp"
    android:text="5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn6"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="175dp"
    android:layout_y="180dp"
    android:text="6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn7"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="9dp"
    android:layout_y="261dp"
    android:text="7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn8"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="94dp"
    android:layout_y="264dp"
    android:text="8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn9"
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="176dp"
    android:layout_y="263dp"
    android:text="9" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn0"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="96dp"
    android:layout_y="348dp"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="248dp"
    android:layout_y="105dp"
    android:text="+" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSub"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="249dp"
    android:layout_y="181dp"
    android:text="-" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMul"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="248dp"
    android:layout_y="267dp"
    android:text="X" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDiv"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="248dp"
    android:layout_y="347dp"
    android:text="/" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEq"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="176dp"
    android:layout_y="347dp"
    android:text="=" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="12dp"
    android:layout_y="346dp"
    android:text="Clear" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Now the problem is that I'm not finding any way to receive and store the second operand from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it appears that both your operands are to be entered into the same `TextView`. First enter your first operand, then press any operator and then in the same `TextView` the second operand will go in. Moreover, each of the operands seem to be handled by individual buttons, so you just need to enter them by clicking on the buttons.

First, enter your first operand, click on an operator, then click on second operand, and then click on `=`. That should work fine for you.

Comment: But the wrong answer is being displayed everytime I press = .

Comment: From a quick scan of your code, what it does is, first assigns your first operand to `i1` , then when you click on any operator, it adds the contents of `i1` to `result` which is `0` initially. Then when you enter another operand, and now press `=`, it won't add this to your result, instead it simply prints the result. From your existing code, you need to press on your operator again to get the actual result computed.

Comment: Yes you're right , but that's what I said in my question . I'm not able to receive and store the 2nd operand for performing an operation.

Comment: A simple solution would be to use another `TextView` for your second operand.

Comment: And a less simpler solution would be(to suffice the existing code) to take a flag to mark which operator was selected, and in the `=` button's listener, check for that flag and apply that operator to result before displaying the result.

Comment: Please suggest a solution using one TextView . I would like to use a single TextView

Comment: Have already suggested that. Because you need to know what operator was clicked on, you will need to store that into a flag. And then in the `=` button's listener,simply perform that operation and then display that result.

Comment: But still the question remains the unanswered : how to store the 2nd operand ?

Comment: You don't need to store the 2nd operand now. It is stored in the `TextView`. And your first operand is in `i1` or `result` for that matter. You just need to know what operator was clicked on, and perform that operation before displaying that result in the `=` button's listener.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks ... Didn't thought about that ... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
'you can try this code..'
package com.example.showoff;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        TextView edittest1;

        Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, add, sub, mul, div, cancel, equal;

        ArrayList<Float> math = new ArrayList<Float>();
        float m1;
        float m2;
        float temp;

        int currentOperation = 0;
        int nextOperation;

        final static int ADD = 1;
        final static int SUBTRACT = 2;
        final static int MULTIPLY =3;
        final static int DIVISION = 4;
        final static int EQUALS = 0;
        final static int CLEAR = 1;
        final static int DONT_CLEAR = 0;
        int clearDisplay = 0;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            edittest1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edittest1);



            one =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNum1Id);
            two =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNum2Id);
            three =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNum3Id);
            four =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNum4Id);
            five =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNum5Id);
            six =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNum6Id);
            seven =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNum7Id);
            eight =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNum8Id);
            nine =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNum9Id);
            zero =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNum0Id);
            add =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNumAddId);
            sub =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNumSubId);
            mul =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNumMulId);
            div =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNumDivId);
            cancel =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNumClearId);
            equal =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNumEqualId);

            edittest1.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true));

            registerListeners();


    }

    private void registerListeners() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    edittest1.setText("");
                }
                clearDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
               edittest1.append("1");

            }
        });

        two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    edittest1.setText("");
                }
                clearDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                edittest1.append("2");

            }
        });

        three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearDisplay == CLEAR) {
                   edittest1.setText("");
                }
                clearDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                edittest1.append("3");

            }
        });
        four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearDisplay == CLEAR) {
                  edittest1.setText("");
                }
                clearDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                edittest1.append("4");

            }
        });

        five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearDisplay == CLEAR) {
                   edittest1.setText("");
                }
                clearDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                edittest1.append("5");

            }
        });

        six.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearDisplay == CLEAR) {
                   edittest1.setText("");
                }
                clearDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                edittest1.append("6");

            }
        });
        seven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    edittest1.setText("");
                }
                clearDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                edittest1.append("7");

            }
        });

        eight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    edittest1.setText("");
                }
                clearDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                edittest1.append("8");

            }
        });

        nine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    edittest1.setText("");
                }
                clearDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                edittest1.append("9");

            }
        });
        zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    edittest1.setText("");
                }
                clearDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                edittest1.append("0");

            }
        });
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                calcLogic(ADD);
                }
            }
        );

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calcLogic(SUBTRACT);
            }               
        });
        mul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calcLogic(MULTIPLY);

            }
        });
        div.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calcLogic(DIVISION);                    
            }
        });
        equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                calcLogic(EQUALS);

            }
        });
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                edittest1.setText("0");
                m1 = 0;
                m2 = 0;
                math.removeAll(math);
                currentOperation = 0;
                nextOperation = 0;    

            }
        });


}
    private void calcLogic(int operator){
         math.add(Float.parseFloat(edittest1.getText().toString()));

            if (operator != EQUALS) {
                nextOperation = operator;
            }
            else if  (operator == EQUALS){
                nextOperation = 0;
                //operator=' ';
            }



            switch (currentOperation) {
            case ADD:               
                m1 = math.get(0);
                m2 = math.get(1);

                math.removeAll(math);

                math.add(m1 + m2);


                edittest1.setText(String.format("%.3f", math.get(0)));



                break;
            case SUBTRACT:
                m1 = math.get(0);
                m2 = math.get(1);

                math.removeAll(math);

                math.add(m1 - m2);

                edittest1.setText(String.format("%.3f", math.get(0)));
                break;
            case MULTIPLY:
                m1 = math.get(0);
                m2 = math.get(1);

                math.removeAll(math);

                math.add(m1 * m2);

                edittest1.setText(String.format("%.3f", math.get(0)));
                break;
            case DIVISION:
                m1 = math.get(0);
                m2 = math.get(1);

                math.removeAll(math);

                math.add(m1 / m2);

                edittest1.setText(String.format("%.3f", math.get(0)));
                break;
            }

            clearDisplay = CLEAR;
            currentOperation = nextOperation;
            if (operator == EQUALS) {
                m1 = 0;
                m2 = 0;
                math.removeAll(math);
            }

        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```